# Im trying to make a simple code where you enter your name and age and it will Say is this information correct but idk how to do the correct thingg

Tags: python

```
print    ("Enter    your details to create your account ")

Username = input("Enter your username " )

age = input("Enter your Age  ")

print("Your username is " + Username)

print("Your age is "+ age)
```

This is my code, but I'm not sure how to do the "is this information correct" thing.

Comment: add another input,  input("is this information correct?")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this is a question about an homework assignment or something like this and could be easily answered by the poster himself if he would take some time to figure it out himself.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Something like this should be added to your code and you'll be done.

```
correct = input("Is this information correct? (y/n)")
```

And this correct variable will hold a value of "y" or "n" which u can check later in your code if you want.

Comment: Thanks but do you know what i have to do to make it so if I put no it will say try again or when I say yes it will say account created?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another prompt at the end like:

```
data = input("Is this information correct?")
if data.lower() in ['y','ye','yes','yep','yeah']:
  # YES
elif data.lower() in ['n','no','nope']:
  # No
else:
  # Invalid input
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution is

```
verified = True if input("Is this information correct? (y/n)").lower() == 'y' else False
```

If `y` or `Y` entered, verified become `True`, otherwise `False`.

**EDIT**

If you need a loop and get values while not verified by user as you mention in comment, you can use

```
verified = False

while not verified:
    print("Enter your details to create your account ")
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    age = input("Enter your Age  ")
    print("Your username is " + username)
    print("Your age is " + age)
    verified = True if input("Is this information correct? (y/n)").lower() == 'y' else False
```